# oauth vs authsub

Tags: authentication, oauth, authsub

why do we need authsub when we have oauth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't.  OAuth is newer.  It didn't exist when AuthSub was developed.  Google still supports AuthSub, however.

Answer (score 0):

Google uses AuthSub as well as OAuth. But OAuth is used by many web service providers like Amazon, Facebook, Twitter, etc.

You can find more about OAuth : http://hueniverse.com/oauth/

http://www.socialtechnologyreview.com/articles/oauth-pros-and-cons-oauth